# Python 2.7 pass method from one script to an other

Tags: python, pickle

I'm really new into Pyhton world. I'm actually doing music, I use a software call Ableton.
What I'm doing is coding 2 scripts for this software.
 
In fact they are selectable in Ableton GUI. Each script is link to an hardware interface. What these scripts do is allowing me to custom the way the hardware interface control the software(Ableton). 
My 2 script are ok and works well, however I would like to be able to send order from one script to the other(to allow to execute an action on the first controller when a button from the second controller is press).
So I have 2 seperate folder with 2 script (I can't use one folder for both because of Ableton who have to run and compil both script independently).
So let's call them **Folder A** and **Folder B**.
In both of these folder I have an **__init__.py** and a **main_code.py file**.
The **main_code.py** files looks like this:

```js
from __future__ import with_statement 
from _Framework.ControlSurface import ControlSurface 
import Live 
import time

class main_code(ControlSurface):

def __init__(self, c_instance):
    ControlSurface.__init__(self, c_instance) 
    with self.component_guard():          
        self._suppress_send_midi = True  
        self.clip = self.selected_scene.clip_slots[self.selected_track_idx].clip
        self._suppress_send_midi = False


    @property
    def selected_track(self):
        return self.song().view.selected_track

    @property
    def selected_track_idx(self):
        return self.tuple_idx(self.song().tracks, self.song().view.selected_track)           

    @property
    def selected_scene(self):
        return self.song().view.selected_scene

    def tuple_idx(self, tuple, obj):
        for i in xrange(0, len(tuple)):
            if (tuple[i] == obj):
                return i
        return(False)
```

As you can see it I use some framework (ControlSurface) and the ableton API (import Live).
What I want to do is to "send" the variable self.clip from one script to the other in order that they both have the same "value"
Sorry for my quote but I don't now anymore if it's a method or what ever ... 
One of my first idea was to use pickle to dumb self.clip in one file and to load it in the other but when I do this I get the error in ableton report crash:

File "/Users/versonator/Jenkins/live/Projects/AppWebConnector/Resources/third_party/lib/pickle.py", line 1362, in dump

9250 ms. RemoteScriptError:   File "/Users/versonator/Jenkins/live/Projects/AppWebConnector/Resources/third_party/lib/pickle.py", line 224, in dump

9250 ms. RemoteScriptError:   File "/Users/versonator/Jenkins/live/Projects/AppWebConnector/Resources/third_party/lib/pickle.py", line 306, in save

9251 ms. RemoteScriptError: RuntimeError
9251 ms. RemoteScriptError: : 
9251 ms. RemoteScriptError: Pickling of "Clip.Clip" instances is not enabled (http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/v2/pickle.html)
9251 ms. RemoteScriptError:

Actually I use pickle like this:

```js
        clip = self.clip
        f = open('/Users/Louis/Desktop/test.pickle', 'wb')  
        pickle.dump(clip, f, -1)       
        f.close()
```

Even I'm not a programmer at all and this looks like a real mess I hope someone may help me to find an other way to do what I whant or to solve my pickle way !

Comment: You could try to add the script which initialises self.clip to the sys path with import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to/script/'); in your script which needs self.clip. Then you should be able to import the script which initialises self.clip and use it in the other.

Comment: If you have the time could you please give me a very short and simple example ? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: self.clip  change depending on the button I press on the hardware interface. Are you sure, the second script will get all of this change ? I don't get how to do it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you call script B.py with Ableton which needs self.clip from script A.py
At the top of script B.py which needs self.clip write:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('\path\to\script\A\')
# You should now be able to import every class from script A 
# and use its methods and functions.
```

e.g.:

B.py

```
from A import main_code

mc = main_code(c_instance) # Don't know what c_instance is or where it comes from, 
                           # but i guess you will :)
mc.selected_track()
```

... and so on

Maybe you will need to create a file called __init__.py in the directory where script A is located in order to make the folder a python package which can be imported by other scripts.

If you need self.clip from A.py you could do something like:

```
mc = main_code(c_instance)
clip = mc.clip
```

Or you could make a function in A.py which returns self.clip:

A.py

```
class main__code(ControlSurface):
    def __init__(self, c_instance):
        ControlSurface.__init__(self, c_instance) 
        with self.component_guard():          
            self._suppress_send_midi = True  
            self.clip = self.selected_scene.clip_slots[self.selected_track_idx].clip
            self._suppress_send_midi = False

     ...

    def getClip(self):
        return self.clip
```

Note:
You will need to check if self.clip changed in A.py and if so update clip in B.py.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer I try this right now ! Do you know what is the global path for application in mac OSX ?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I'm not very familiar with mac. :/